Datastream validation issues 'One or more tables in the stream's include list weren't found or Datastream couldn't read from them.'
I have set up a google datastream postgres to bigquery.   My publication, replication slot area all created as well as my replication user, also my replication user has been assigned select access and usage access to all target schemas.
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA rides TO replication_user;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA rides TO replication_user;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA rides TO replication_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA rides GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO replication_user;

I can see my DB as the connection test passes, but when I get to the final validation step I get this.
"One or more tables in the stream's include list weren't found or Datastream couldn't read from them."
Tried adding catalog and information_schema access to my replication user
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA information_schema TO replication_user;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA information_schema TO replication_user;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA pg_catalog TO replication_user;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA pg_catalog TO replication_user;

But seems to have no affect.
Can anyone see anything I am missing?



You have to be careful with your application architecture, our application uses multiple applications, all under different schemas...each schema having its own application login.   It turns out when Entity framework creates tables and other objects under a specific schema, the root user cannot even access data in them (I was able to confirm this in the console).
The solution was to log into each separate schema and run the access assignment commands from there, root could not assign it, even though it does not error out when you run the commands, the assigned account will not be able to access the data.
